# How to force myself to code more elegantly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, coding-efficiency

I've noticed that my coding style tends to be very brute force compared to others. For example, a practice problem required us to create a cipher via a class. The cipher would accept a string and use two series of alphabets to encode and decode the string. For example:

```
map1 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
map2 = "etaoinshrdlucmfwypvbgkjqxz"

cipher = Cipher(map1, map2);
cipher.encode("abc") => "eta"
```

I successfully completed this practice problem by writing the following:

```
class Cipher(object):
    def __init__(self, map1, map2):
        self.map1=map1
        self.map2=map2

    def encode(self, string):
        string=list(string)
        string_pos=[self.map1.index(i) if i.isalpha() else i for i in string]
        string_enc=[self.map2[i] if isinstance(i, int) else i for i in string_pos]
        return ''.join(string_enc)

    def decode(self, string):
        string=list(string)
        string_pos=[self.map2.index(i) if i.isalpha() else i for i in string]
        string_dec=[self.map1[i] if isinstance(i, int) else i for i in string_pos]
        return ''.join(string_dec)
```

However, someone else completed the same practice problem in what I see as a far more straight forward manner:

```
from string import maketrans

class Cipher(object):
    def __init__(self, map1, map2):
        self.encode_table = maketrans(map1, map2)
        self.decode_table = maketrans(map2, map1)
    def encode(self, string):
        return string.translate(self.encode_table)
    def decode(self, string):
        return string.translate(self.decode_table)
```

How can I force/teach myself to start writing more elegant and straight forward code and gradually move away from brute force-like code? What reading resources would you recommend for this? Are there any tricks you know that could help, such as "if you see yourself using x, remember that y does the same more elegantly?"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read the documentation of the standard library. You will learn the true power of python.

Comment: Also, review the code you wrote. six months ago and see if you can still understand what it is doing.

Comment: The biggest help I've found is to read the code of larger, well-maintained projects (such as Django, requests, etc.) The people working on those projects have been doing it for years and the code quality is often far higher than anything else you can find. Learn what their principles are (most projects have a contribution guide that can give you some hints as to this) and then adapt them to your own everyday use.

Comment: @RushyPanchal thank you, I never thought to look at other projects as a source of learning. Aside from Django, what other projects are good to learn from?

Comment: Try to rewrite your solution so that it uses dictionaries to look up the encoded/decoded values (that's more or less what the `maketrans` version does, though more efficiently).  Start thinking about the algorithmic complexity of your solutions.  Read the documentation.  Submit answers on Stack Overflow, and internalize peoples criticism of them.  If possible, pair program with someone who knows what they're doing.  Further on, learn  several programming languages/paradigms.  Knowing something like C really forces you to understand what's actually happening in the computer, which is invaluable

Comment: FWIW, there are various problems with that 2nd version. In Python 3, `maketrans` and `translate` are methods of `str`. And that code shadows the `string` module with the local `string` parameter.

Comment: I was about to write a full answer about it but here are the baselines: read style guides such as [the Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3) and [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Listen to other developpers comment about readability: we have tools such as GitHub and Stackoverflow to share code with thousands, more than ever readability matters. Then know your standard libraries, I often see SO question that present 10 lines of code that can be rewritten as one built-in, know libs such as `re`, `string`, `itertools`, `functools`, etc. Finally, code a lot

Comment: We should all encourage the use of libraries instead of reinventing the wheel, in the end this is what this question is about and that's why it does not seem like opinion-based question for me.

Comment: The bottom line: if you want to write good code you need to read good code, written by good coders. And don't just read it, play with it. Modify it and extend it until it becomes a horrible mess that you have to delete and start again. :) Eventually the good patterns will rub off on you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question is: "Practice creates masters". Write code, review your code, refactor your code. With time you will gain more and more experience and write better code. As resource I recommend reading "Clean Code" by Robert C. Martin, "Pragmatic Programmer" by Andy Hund and Dave Thomas, "Practical object-oriented desing" by Sandi Metz. I think you will get a better developer, if you read them.